# Coefficient of variances by column to each dataframe in a list of dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I have written a function to calculate Coefficient of variances that I want to a apply to a list of dataframes.  The function executes however returns an unexpected outcome.  Instead of returning the result for each column of the each dataframe it is also producing additional values that do not make sense.

A sample of my list of dataframes below

```
list(Fe = structure(list(Determination_No = 1:6, `2` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `3` = c(56.83, 56.54, 56.18, 56.5, 56.51, 
56.34), `4` = c(56.39, 56.43, 56.53, 56.31, 56.47, 56.35), `5` = c(56.32, 
56.29, 56.31, 56.32, 56.39, 56.32), `7` = c(56.48, 56.4, 56.54, 
56.43, 56.73, 56.62), `8` = c(56.382, 56.258, 56.442, 56.258, 
56.532, 56.264), `10` = c(56.3, 56.5, 56.2, 56.5, 56.7, 56.5), 
    `12` = c(56.11, 56.46, 56.1, 56.35, 56.36, 56.37)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame"), SiO2 = structure(list(Determination_No = 1:6, 
    `2` = c(7.63, 7.65, 7.73, 7.67, 7.67, 7.67), `3` = c(7.84, 
    7.69, 7.59, 7.77, 7.74, 7.64), `4` = c(7.67, 7.74, 7.62, 
    7.81, 7.66, 7.8), `5` = c(7.91, 7.84, 7.96, 7.87, 7.84, 7.92
    ), `7` = c(7.77, 7.83, 7.76, 7.78, 7.65, 7.74), `8` = c(7.936, 
    7.685, 7.863, 7.838, 7.828, 7.767), `10` = c(7.872684992, 
    7.851291827, 7.872684992, 7.722932832, 7.680146501, 7.615967003
    ), `12` = c(7.64, 7.71, 7.71, 7.65, 7.82, 7.68)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame"), Al2O3 = structure(list(Determination_No = 1:6, 
    `2` = c(2.01, 2.02, 2.03, 2.01, 2.02, 2), `3` = c(2.01, 2.01, 
    2, 2.02, 2.02, 2.03), `4` = c(2, 2.03, 1.99, 2.01, 2.01, 
    2.01), `5` = c(2.02, 2.02, 2.05, 2.03, 2.02, 2.03), `7` = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `8` = c(2.053, 2.044, 2.041, 2.038, 
    2.008, 2.02), `10` = c(2.002830415, 2.021725042, 2.021725042, 
    1.983935789, 2.002830415, 2.021725042), `12` = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame"), 
    TiO2 = structure(list(Determination_No = 1:6, `2` = c(0.07, 
    0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07), `3` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), `4` = c(0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07), `5` = c(0.07, 
    0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07), `7` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), `8` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `10` = c(0.066721378, 
    0.066721378, 0.066721378, 0.066721378, 0.066721378, 0.066721378
    ), `12` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L
    ), class = "data.frame"), Mn = structure(list(Determination_No = 1:6, 
        `2` = c(0.194, 0.209, 0.218, 0.22, 0.213, 0.217), `3` = c(0.222, 
        0.214, 0.21, 0.212, 0.205, 0.213), `4` = c(0.21, 0.21, 
        0.21, 0.22, 0.23, 0.2), `5` = c(0.23, 0.21, 0.22, 0.21, 
        0.2, 0.22), `7` = c(0.197, 0.238, 0.205, 0.223, 0.205, 
        0.214), `8` = c(0.217, 0.221, 0.237, 0.213, 0.227, 0.232
        ), `10` = c(0.21, 0.21, 0.22, 0.23, 0.21, 0.22), `12` = c(NA, 
        0.24, 0.23, 0.23, 0.22, 0.23)), row.names = c(NA, -6L
    ), class = "data.frame"), CaO = structure(list(Determination_No = 1:6, 
        `2` = c(0.08, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.08, 0.07), `3` = c(0.08, 
        0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07), `4` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA), `5` = c(0.08, 0.07, 0.08, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07), 
        `7` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `8` = c(0.07, 0.071, 
        0.07, 0.067, 0.071, 0.07), `10` = c(0.069959326, 0.069959326, 
        0.069959326, 0.069959326, 0.069959326, 0.069959326), 
        `12` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L), class = "data.frame"))
```

function below

```
labCV <- function(x,...){
  LabMean <- round(mapply(mean, x[-1], na.rm = T),digits = 2)
  Lab.GrandMean <- median(LabMean,na.rm=T)
  lab.SD <- round(mapply(sd, x[-1], na.rm = T), digits = 2)
  SD.All <- unlist(x[-1]) #convert all the values to a vector
  
  lab.cv <- as.vector(lab.SD/LabMean) *100
  lab.cvall <- ((SD.All / Lab.GrandMean) * 100)
  lab.cv.T <- format(round(lab.cv,2),nsmall = 2)
  lab.cvall.T <- format(round(lab.cvall,2),nsmall =2)
  CV.Summary <- c("Coeff. Variation", lab.cv.T, lab.cvall.T)
  return(CV.Summary)
  }

df.cv <- lapply(df, function(x) labCV(x,na.rm=T))
```

I only expect a result for each lab in each dataframe however I am getting

```
c("Coeff. Variation", "  NA", "0.39", "0.14", "0.05", "0.21", 
"0.21", "0.32", "0.27", `21` = "    NA", `22` = "    NA", `23` = "    NA", 
`24` = "    NA", `25` = "    NA", `26` = "    NA", `31` = "100.74", 
`32` = "100.23", `33` = " 99.59", `34` = "100.16", `35` = "100.18", 
`36` = " 99.88", `41` = " 99.96", `42` = "100.04", `43` = "100.21", 
`44` = " 99.82", `45` = "100.11", `46` = " 99.89", `51` = " 99.84", 
`52` = " 99.79", `53` = " 99.82", `54` = " 99.84", `55` = " 99.96", 
`56` = " 99.84", `71` = "100.12", `72` = " 99.98", `73` = "100.23", 
`74` = "100.04", `75` = "100.57", `76` = "100.37", `81` = " 99.95", 
`82` = " 99.73", `83` = "100.06", `84` = " 99.73", `85` = "100.22", 
`86` = " 99.74", `101` = " 99.80", `102` = "100.16", `103` = " 99.63", 
`104` = "100.16", `105` = "100.51", `106` = "100.16", `121` = " 99.47", 
`122` = "100.09", `123` = " 99.45", `124` = " 99.89", `125` = " 99.91", 
`126` = " 99.93")
```

I didn't expect anything after 9 rows/entries. Not sure where I have gone wrong.

Comment: The expected calculations are not quite clear to me, and I'm not sure I'm interpreting how the data is set up- may need to spell out what each calculation is expected to do to make sure you get the answer you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following got the desired result

```
labCV <- function(x,...){
  lab.cv <- mapply(sd, x[-1], na.rm = T)/mapply(mean, x[-1], na.rm = T) *100
  LabCV.all <- round(sd(unlist(x[-1]), na.rm = T), digits = 4)/mean(mapply(mean, x[-1], na.rm = T),na.rm=T) *100
  cv.summmary <- c(lab.cv,LabCV.all)
  return(cv.summmary)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you only need `lab.cv.T` in the output.

```
labCV <- function(x,...){
   LabMean <- round(mapply(mean, x[-1], na.rm = T),digits = 2)
   #...
   #...
   CV.Summary <- c("Coeff. Variation", lab.cv.T)
   return(CV.Summary)
}
```